# Google Static Maps API not displaying markers

Tags: api, google-maps, logic, loading, google-maps-static-api

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-33.882257,151.210243&zoom=13&markers=size:mid|color:red|label:E|-33.882257151.210243&size=250x188&sensor=false

Hi, I have this url and i'm unable to display markers on it? What am I doing wrong with this?

-Thanks, Jackson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma in the marker position in the URL:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-33.882257,151.210243&zoom=13&markers=size:mid|color:red|label:E|-33.882257,151.210243&size=250x188&sensor=false

(should be: -33.882257,151.210243)